# Unable to start Genymotion in android studio

Tags: windows, android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

When i am starting Genymotion getting error , 
[image]

Every solution on other site is provided for MAC but not for windows so please tell me how to resolve this issue on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall your virtualbox and re install and don't touch anything from the virtualbox ,just launch your genymotion from android studio please check task manager as enough memory while running your Virtualbox .