# Genymotion fail to start new Virtual Device

Tags: android, genymotion

When I start new Virtual Device via Genymotion, it appear and close immediatly. I just try to create a divice with API 18 but it not success. I saw this log in terminal:

> Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection,
>   IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!! OpenGL connected to
>   192.168.56.101:25000 Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections player:
>   ../../../../../../../src/mesa/drivers/dri/i915/i915_fragprog.c:1225:
>   i915BindProgram: Assertion `p->on_hardware == 0' failed.

Do anyone can solve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524597/unable-to-start-genymotion-in-android-studio/34525237?noredirect=1#comment56832723_34525237

Comment: Sorry but maybe it's not work for me. :(